# Magento featured products by category

Tags: magento

I'm trying to adjust a module to give me featured products by a particular category. I *think* its close but no cigar yet. Apparently I can't use getSingleton("catalog/layer") here to get the current category ID. Currently the module spits out featured products, but they are not associated with the specific category you're on.

Any tips for getting the current category here? You'll see what I tried below in  /* THIS IS MY ADDITION */ comments to pull products by the current category.

```
class Adodis_Featuredproducts_Block_Product_Featured extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{

        protected $_priceBlockDefaultTemplate = 'catalog/product/price_fix.phtml';


        public $totproduct,$opt;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $totproduct=Mage::getStoreConfig("adodis_featuredproducts/adodis_block/adodis_featuredproduct_block_product_number");
            $opt=Mage::getStoreConfig('adodis_featuredproducts/adodis_general/adodis_featuredproducts_display_type');
            parent::__construct();

            /* THIS IS MY ADDITION */ 
        $layer = Mage::getSingleton(‘catalog/layer’);
            var_dump($layer);
            $_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
            /* END MY ADDITION */ 

            $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
            $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
            $todayDate  = $product->getResource()->formatDate(time());
            $products   = $product->setStoreId($storeId)->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('featured_products', array('Yes'=>true))

                /* THIS IS MY ADDITION */ 
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $currentCategoryId))
                /* END MY ADDITION */ 

                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'), 'inner')
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date'), 'left');
           /* @var $products Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection */
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
          if($opt=='block'){
          $products->setOrder('hot_deals')->setPageSize($totproduct)->setCurPage(1);
          }
          else{
            $products->setOrder('hot_deals')->setPageSize(4)->setCurPage(1);
          }
            $this->setProductCollection($products);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using IN when you only need to match one value?

Comment: Not sure, haven't gotten that far, but the main problem is $_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory(); is NULL, so for some reason the current category isn't getting retrieved properly

Comment: Have you tried `Mage::registry('current_category')`?  As you navigate the site, this value is automatically set by Magento.

Comment: That helped, Thanks @BrianVPS , I also had to change the filter as seen below. Since i can't find to seem any legit documentation on this stuff i've just been hacking my way through it.

Comment: Yeah, part of the fun of Magento is learning how and where to find answers.  Keep SO close by...this community is GREAT for answering all kinds of questions!  GL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution here:

```
        /* THIS IS MY ADDITION */ 
        $_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        /* END MY ADDITION */ 

        $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $todayDate  = $product->getResource()->formatDate(time());
        $products   = $product->setStoreId($storeId)->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('featured_products', array('Yes'=>true))
            /* THIS IS MY ADDITION */ 
            ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
            /* END MY ADDITION */
```